# Common.Logging configuration. Troubles with log4net adapter

Tags: .net, log4net, app-config, log4net-configuration

Got the following exception

> Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration
>   section 'common/logging'.

while trying to run next code

```
Common.Logging.ILog logger = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log.txt" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ManagementModel.csdl|res://*/Model.ManagementModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.ManagementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\Management.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above configuration seems correct to me (unless I'm missing something obvious), & I was hit by a similar problem when I copied a configuration that worked in another project - it turns out I was using a "Client Profile" version of .NET Framework as a target.

To change this, right click on the project on the solution explorer & select properties.  If the "Target Framework" dropdown is down as `.NET Framework X Client Profile`, switch it to `.NET Framework X`, where `X` is the version of .NET you're using.

Comment: Had a similar problem - the issue was in the NuGet packages. Removed everything using Solution > Manage NuGet Packages (under Installed Packaged), and only added back the Common.Logging package.